# CentOS 7.9 not reporting full version number after recompiling kernel

Tags: centos, rhel, linux-kernel, kernel, compiling

I needed to enable SCSI support in CentOS 7.9 so I followed the instructions here:

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos(2f)I_need_the_Kernel_Source.html

to add SCSI support and recompile, which worked as expected, but instead of uname -r reporting `3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64`, it only reports `3.10.0`, and the vmlinuz files it creates in /boot are also named this way.

This despite all the paths in the rpmbuild directories having the full name.

The `UTS_RELEASE` entry in the `include/generated/utsrelease.h` file was `3.10.0` so I edited it and recompiled, but it's doing the same thing.

How do I recompile the kernel so that `uname -r` reports the correct version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `uname -r` will only give the output of `VERSION`, `PATCHLEVEL` & `SUBLEVEL` as defined by the kernel Makefile as all other settings would by default be blank. In this case, `3.10.0`.

However, there is also `EXTRAVERSION` within the Makefile & `LOCALVERSION` which can be set during config. As such I would have expected `LOCALVERSION` to be set to `-1160.108.1`, but for some reason  in this case, it is not.

You can change it by altering `General setup` -> `Local version - append to kernel release`. It is just free form text.

You should note that although you expect it to show `3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64`, I have not seen a single kernel which has ever added on the `el7.x86_64` part.

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding it to the string section of `LOCALVERSION`, but it was adding it to `EXTRAVERSION` in the Makefile that did the trick.